# Algorithm to create n-th level of nested patterns in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, recursion

As explained in [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/133601/1176601), it is not possible to create regex to match arbitrary nested pattern. But is it possible to create an algorithm that would generate a regex of n-th level of "nesteness"?

basically, i want to replace `trim(whatever)` with `rtrim(ltrim(whatever))`

i managed to create 3 levels by hand (javascript syntax):

```js
level[1] = /\(([^()]*)\)/g
level[2] = /\(((?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*)\)/g
level[3] = /\(((?:(?:(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*)*\((?:(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*)*\))*[^()]*)\)/g
```

here are some test data:

```
1st(ddd) + 1st(ddd)
2nd(dd(d))
3rd(a(b) + (cd(h) + d(dfas) + zzz))
4th(a(b(c(d))))
8th(a(b(c(d(e(f(g()))))))
```

i know that at every level `[^()]*` needs to be replaced with noncapturing group that can contain parentheses, but i'm not sure how to **generalize the algoritm for n-th level**...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think about it more theoretically: a match for parenthesis nested `n` deep is just parenthesis around matches for `n-1` or less deep (with at least one exactly `n-1` deep).

We can give a recursive definition of the regexes. Let `X[n]` be the regex for nesting exactly `n` levels, and `Y[n]` be the regex for a string containing brackets with any level of nesting up to `n` levels, so:

```
X[n] = \( (Y[n-2] X[n-1])+ Y[n-2] \)

Y[n] = [^()]* ( \( Y[n-1] \) [^()]* )*
```

with `Y[0] = X[0] = [^()]*` (no nesting) and `X[1] = \([^()]*\)`. (I'm not bothering with the details of non-capturing groups etc yet, and the spaces are just for readability.)

Writing an algorithm based on this should be quite easy.

---

The regexes from these new (less mutually recursive) definitions get longer much much more slowly (they are polynomial rather than exponential).

Let `l[n]` be the length of `X[n]`, and `L[n]` be the length of `Y[n]`, then (the constant terms are just the hardcoded characters in each one):

```
L[n] = 19 + L[n-1] = 19*n + L[0] = 19*n + 6

l[n] = 3 + L[n-2] + l[n-1] + 2 + L[n-2] + 2
     = 7 + 2 * L[n-2] + l[n-1]
     = -57 + 38 * n + l[n-1]
```

with the appropriate initial conditions for `l[0]` and `l[1]`. Recurrence relations of this form have quadratic solutions, so this is only `O(n^2)`. Much better.

(For others, I had a previous definition of `Y[n]` was `Y[n] = Y[n-1] | X[n]`; this extra recursion meant that the length of the `X` regex was `O(2.41^n)`, which sucks a lot.)

(The new definition of `Y` is a tantalising hint that there might even be a way of writing `X` that is linear in `n`. I don't know though, and I have a feeling the extra restriction on `X` of exact length means it is impossible.)

---

The following is some Python code that computes the regexes above, you can probably translate it to javascript without too much trouble.

```
# abbreviation for the No Parenthesis regex
np = "[^()]*"

# compute Y[n] from Y[n-1]
def next_y(y_n1):
    return np + "(?:\(" + y_n1 + "\)" + np + ")*"

# compute X[n] from X[n-1] and Y[n-2]
def next_x(x_n1, y_n2):
    return "\((?:" + y_n2 + x_n1 + ")+" + y_n2 + "\)"

# compute [X[n], Y[n], Y[n-1]]
# (to allow us to make just one recursive call at each step)
def XY(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [np, # X[0]
                np, # Y[0]
                ""] # unused
    elif n == 1:
        return ["\([^()]*\)", # X[1]
                next_y(np),   # Y[1]
                np]           # Y[0]

    x_n1, y_n1, y_n2 = XY(n-1) # X[n-1], Y[n-1], Y[n-2]

    return [next_x(x_n1, y_n2), # X[n]
            next_y(y_n1),       # Y[n]
            y_n1]               # Y[n-1]

# wrapper around XY to compute just X[n]
def X(n):
    return XY(n)[0]

# wrapper around XY to compute just Y[n]
def Y(n):
    return XY(n)[1]
```

Comment: thanks, O() isn't a problem, i hope noone will use more than 10 nested parentheses, i'll have a look at it during weekend :)

Comment: @deathApril, I just vastly improved the answer by changing the definition of `Y`. This reduces the size of the regex for `n=10` from ~45000 to ~1500 (so even for `10` the O() was making the regex huge!). (I understand you aren't worried about large `n`, but I find this question very interesting (thanks for asking it!), so I'm doing the analysis anyway.)

Comment: @deathApril, and now there is some code (although Python rather than Javascript).

Comment: glad to hear it is so interesting for you - less work for me ;)) python is ok,, i'll just run it and use the resulting regex in a notepad++ macro (or i create a simple web app to do it, if other team members would want to use it) - i will accept after i test it a bit more ;)