# Regex to match contents in last pair of brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript regular expressions, how can I match the contents in the last set of brackets?

```
input = "the string (contains) things like (35) )( with (foobar) and )( stuff";

desired_output = "foobar"
```

Everything I have tried over-matches or fails entirely.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I have a feeling this fits the definition of something which is impossible to parse with a regular expression.

Comment: Your original question was OK, but I'm pretty sure your current example is impossible by regex. Can you define what you mean by "last"? (note that the `( with .. and )` *ends* the last, whilst `(foobar)`'s opening bracket is the last opening bracket with a matching closing bracket.  And must the set of brackets have no brackets within? For example, one could make a case for `(foobar) and)` being the "last" set of brackets (the last-occurring opening bracket with a close remaining in the string, and the last closing bracket in the string)

Comment: Do you want just to get the contents or to have exact match?

Comment: have a look at first level example in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10447423/1176601

Comment: I'm after the contents of the last set that contains no parenthesis.   eg: "foobar"

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at matching, otherwise people would happily use them to parse HTML.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to match parentheses that do not contain other parentheses, for example:

```
var tokens = input.match(/\([^()]*\)/g);
var last = tokens.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks Kobi.  That matches all the ones that don't contain parenthesis.   eg: (contains), (35) and (foobar).   Is there anyway to only match the contents of the last set without the pop?  eg: foobar

Comment: Also, it seems pop returns the first match (eg: contains), not the last (eg: foobar)

Comment: @mgm: [here a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2kUk/) for this answer which cuts the brackets.

Comment: Thanks scessor!  That works great.  I just added a little error checking so that it doesn't pop null and it seems rock solid.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Or as a one liner...

```
var last = input.match(/\([^()]*\)/g).pop().replace(/(\(|\))/g,"").replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,"");
```